# Вывод свойства в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Есть список услуг, который выводится через ItemsControl, у каждой услуги есть кнопка "Редактировать" и при нажатии на неё в текстбокс должно подставляться название услуги, но ничего не подставляется, в чём может быть дело? P.s русские наименования уберу.

Класс MainViewModel:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Service_import selectedService;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceImport> Services { get; set; }

    // Команда добавления нового объекта
    private RelayCommand addCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
              (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  //Services.Insert(0, service);
                  //SelectedServices = service;
                  //MessageBox.Show(Services.Count.ToString());
                  Service_import service = obj as Service_import;
                  //MessageBox.Show(s.Наименование_услуги.ToString());
                  selectedService = service;
              }));
        }
    }

    public Service_import Наименование_услуги
    {
        get { return selectedService; }
        set
        {
            selectedService = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Наименование_услуги");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class Service_import
{
    public string Наименование_услуги { get; set; }
    public string Главное_изображение { get; set; }
    public string Длительность { get; set; }
    public string Стоимость { get; set; }
    public string Действующая_скидка { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> С_учётом_скидки { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textboxPanel1" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.Наименование_услуги, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0"/>
```

Comment: `selectedService = service;` => `Наименование_услуги = service;` (с названиями ужас!).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не сработало, ахахх

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А нет, сработало, спасибо большое)

Comment: [Общие соглашения об именовании](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)